# Tcp/udp client/server Programs over Ipv6 in java

Tags: java

i am struggling with

IPV6 programing

please help me or guide to me to ipv6

if it is posible please send reference site for following programs

Tcp/upd client /server examples over ipv6

Advanced Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a question at all, but [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/ipv6_guide/index.html) could be useful. In general, using IPv6 is the same as using IPv4. You can always use network names instead of IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

First, use google (or any other search engine):
https://www.google.com/?q=Tcp/udp%20client/server%20Programs%20over%20Ipv6%20in%20java

Find a interesting link like this:
http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/